# MouseMove Event, no decent examples

Tags: c#, wpf

Can't get my head around this, there are no decent examples on how to setup an event listener for a mouse move event.

I can find references like [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.mouse.mousemove(v=vs.110).aspx) and [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.mousemove(v=vs.110).aspx) but that doesn't really help...

How can I do something like this:

```
public event MouseEventHandler(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
     //Manage mouse move event   
     //Get X, Y position of mouse ect...
}
```

**Edit:**

I'm getting two errors:

> A static readonly field cannot be assigned to (except in a static
>   constructor or a variable initializer)
>
> Operator '+=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'RoutedEvent' and
>   'method group'

These errors are on this line: `Mouse.MouseMoveEvent += mouseEventHandler`.

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Mouse.MouseMoveEvent += mouseEventHandler;
}

public void mouseEventHandler(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    Point mousePosition = e.GetPosition(this);
}
```

Comment: System.Windows.Input.Mouse.MouseMove += MouseEventHandler;

Comment: -_- I did not think it was that simple... Thanks, make it an answer?

Comment: @JerrySwitalski See update

Comment: Ah I see now, sorry that is routed event.

Comment: Are you SURE this is WPF and not Winforms?  Your event handlers look like WinForms events.  If it is WinForms the tags on the question should be modified to reflect that.  Actually, that may be your problem.  You are trying to use WinForms handlers in a WPF application.

Comment: @BradleyUffner All event handlers have the same two parameters: Sender object and event arguments object. How is this in any way relevant to Forms?

Comment: Wpf uses routed events

Comment: @BradleyUffner And [`MouseEvent`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.mousemoveevent.aspx) is a routed event, and [MouseEventArgs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.mouseeventargs.aspx) inherits from `RoutedEventArgs`…

Comment: Yes, but typically you actually declare them as RoutedEvent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply attach an event handler to the [`MouseMove`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.mousemove.aspx) event of any [`UIElement`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Windows.UIElement.aspx).

For example, you could add it to a [`Window`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.aspx) in the code-behind like this:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.MouseMove += Window_MouseMove;
    }

    private void Window_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Mouse moved");
    }
}
```

The alternative to attaching the event handler in C# in code-behind is to set it using XAML, e.g. for above window, it could be like this:

```
<Window …
    MouseMove="Window_MouseMove">
```

Note that you still need to declare the `Window_MouseMove` method in the code-behind.

Comment: This is the finally best direct answer. I got lost here ;)

Comment: FINALLY! Yeah, the answer I was looking for. Should of added WPF as a tag in the first place, but it was added before half of these comments where made, who uses WinForms these days? aha

Answer (score 2):

EDIT:

If you are using Forms, you probably want to use:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.mousemove(v=vs.110).aspx

Like:

```
System.Windows.Forms.MouseMove += MouseEventHandler
```

Take in mind you need a instance of Forms, and use it directly like:

```
this.MouseMove += MouseEventHandler
```

Comment: There is no `MouseMove` event on the [`Mouse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Windows.Input.Mouse.aspx) type, unless you are referring to the attached property, which will still not work like this at all.

Comment: @poke, yes I see it now.

Comment: This answer still contains mostly false information: OP is using WPF not Forms; there is no `System.Windows.Forms.MouseMove` (`System.Windows.Forms` is a namespace, so `MouseMove` would be a type, and how would `+=` with a type work?!); there is no `System.Windows.Input.Mouse.MouseMove` either. All that mumbled into a quite messy answer that. Please correct the answer, or delete it, because the way it is now, it is more harmful than helpful. I don’t get why this is still being upvoted.

Answer (score 1):

Because of the InitializeComponent() function in your constructor I guess you are using Winforms using the designer in visual studio

Apart from the correct answers others gave I want to point out to you that subscribing to events in visual studio is really easy in the designer.

The designer is the part where you draw the form, add all the buttons, text boxes etc.

To add an event handler for your mouse move (or for any event that any component in your form might raise), do the following:

- Select the component that should react on the your move move, for instance a button, or the form you are designing
- Go to the properties window of this component (there are a lot of possibilities of how to do this, one of it is via menu view - properties
- In the properties window you see a lightning flash sign. If you click on it, you see a list of most events the component can generate
- One of these events is the mousemove. Type a function name, or double click on the event to generate a default name.
- The event handler is generated with all correct parameters and the code of the event handler is shown

Comment: Yeah using WPF. `InitializeComponent()` is added by Visual Studio when creating a WPF Window.